# Python Regex to find any word within a string that has a comma

Tags: python, sql, regex

I'm trying to process some SQL code to find the parts of a select statement that would need to be grouped farther down in a query. For example:

In the string `"Select person, age, name, sum(count distinct arrests) from..."`

I would want `"sum(count"` returned, because it's the only part of this string that has white space on either side and includes an open parenthesis.

I have been trying different things but am struggling.

I've tried re.compile(r'\W.*[)]') and am getting either way too much back or nothing at all.

Comment: your title and question don't match up in what you want. Can you try to clarify your question and provide [mcve] of your attempt

Comment: Are you trying to match words with commas or words with white space on either side?

Comment: words with white space on either side which have a "(" as a character within that word

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/andialbrecht/sqlparse.

Comment: @S420L I've added an answer for you. Is that helped you?

Answer (score 1):

Use  pattern `(\w+\(\w+)\s+`

**Ex:**

```
import re

s = "Select person, age, name, sum(count distinct arrests) from..."
print(re.search(r"(\w+\(\w+)\s+", s).group(1))
```

**Output:**

```
sum(count
```

Comment: Thanks! This mostly works, however I have a use case where one word is "COUNT(DISTINCT(case when etc...)" where I would like "COUNT(DISTINCT(case" returned and with this code I am only getting "DISTINCT(case", it's dropping the word in front of it

Answer (score 0):

If the match can also occur at the start of the string, you could use lookarounds to assert what is on the left and in the right is not a non whitespace char `\S` and use a repeating group `(?:...)+` to match that 1+ times.

```
(?<!\S)(?:\w+\(\w+)+(?!\S)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Udj7OH/2)

That will match `COUNT(DISTINCT(case` and `sum(count`

Answer (score 0):

How about a **non-regex** way with `split()` and `list-comprehension`

```
some_list = "Select person, age, name, sum(count distinct arrests) from...".split(' ')
matching = [s for s in some_list if "(" in s][0]
print(matching) # sum(count


some_list = "COUNT(DISTINCT(case when etc...)".split(' ')
matching = [s for s in some_list if "(" in s][0]
print(matching) # COUNT(DISTINCT(case
```

**WORKING DEMO:** https://rextester.com/ZKJU83182